# NLog nlogger snippet not working Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, code-snippets, nlog

Does anyone know how to get Nlog's nlogger snippet to work in Visual Studio 2012 like it did in 2010? I don't see anything on their forum or on the internet when googing around. Seems like something that people who use Nlog would want back.

Comment: Any one out there know this one :(

Comment: Im wondering the exactly same thing.

Comment: @publicENEMY - Seriously. I cannot be the only one who uses this thing and VS2012??

Comment: You can use [snippet designer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/B08B0375-139E-41D7-AF9B-FAEE50F68392)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Haven't worked out how to get the real snippet installed, so I manually created a snippet to perform the same function as the original did.

Create the file nlogger.snippet in the following folder:

```
My Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Code Snippets\Visual C#\My Code Snippets
```

The contents of the file should be as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
    <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
        <Header>
            <Title>
                NLog Logger Snippet
            </Title>
            <Shortcut>nlogger</Shortcut>
        </Header>
        <Snippet>
            <Code Language="CSharp">
                <![CDATA[private static NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();]]>
            </Code>
        </Snippet>
    </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: FWIW: I borrowed your snippet above and created one to make my debug logging lines in Visual Studio 2013. But it didn't work when I just laid the file down in the My Code Snippets folder so, I moved the file elsewhere and then used the MSDN instructions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx) for importing a snippet file. The first time I tried importing I got an 'invalid file' error so I tweaked it a bit to look more exactly like the MS example and second try worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @agunn above, I'm posting the snippet that imports properly for me in VS2013:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <Title>NLog Logger Snippet</Title>
      <Description>Adds the logger object</Description>
      <Shortcut>nlogger</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="CSharp"
            Kind="any">
        <![CDATA[private static readonly Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();]]>
      </Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```