# VisualStudio 2012 and NLogger

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nlog, nuget-package

According to some post on the web, I noticed that there is compatibility issue between VisualStudio 2012 and Nlog.

So google bring me on [this web page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nlog-users/PSurKJnDg2I) and advised me to use Nuget package installer instead of classical installer but it did'nt work. (I can't see the nlogger template in the list...

Then, I found [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588131/nlog-nlogger-snippet-not-working-visual-studio-2012), and it also didn't work. I precise that I'm using the "update 2" of VS2012. I'm looking for a workaround tight now.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What template are you looking for? The config package doesn't install templates but places a default NLog.config file in the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the `nlogger` code snippet, I didn't find it either. But it is not a blocker.
So instead of typing `nlogger` and pressing two tabs, just use this code:

```cs
private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

I am using the nuget package for nlog, and worked without any problems (minus the code snippet).

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to post pictures, so... What you are looking for:

**NLog**

Nlog - Advanced .NET and Silverlight Logging

Current version (July of 2013): 2.0.1.2